# For which integer sequences $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_t$ is it true that a certain relationship with lcm and gcd holds?

Tags: number-theory

The relationship is $\operatorname{gcd}(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_t)\cdot\operatorname{lcm}(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_t)=a_1\cdot a_2\cdot\dots\cdot a_t$. I think this holds for every sequence of length less than $3$, although I'm not sure how to start with this one.

Comment: Let $p$ be a prime. With what exponent does it appear on the left and on the right hand sides?

Comment: $\prod_{k=1}^n a_k = \text{gcd}(a_1, \cdots, a_n)^{n-1}\text{lcm}(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle That's not correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't see why, can you enlighten me?

Comment: @Petite: it's not correct because you can easily write down counterexamples. For example, $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 6 \neq \gcd(2, 3, 6)^2 \text{lcm}(2, 3, 6)$; the LHS is $36$ but the RHS is $12$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh yeah, I missed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $$a_i = \prod_{k=1}^np_k^{a_{k,i}}$$ where $a_{k,i} \geq 0$.
$$\gcd(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_t) = \prod_{k=1}^np_k^{\min_ia_{k,i}}$$
$$\text{lcm}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_t) = \prod_{k=1}^np_k^{\max_ia_{k,i}}$$
Hence, we need
$$\sum_{i=1}^t a_{k,i} = \max_ia_{k,i} + \min_ia_{k,i}$$
If $t=2$, this always holds true. For $t>2$, note that this would mean $a_{k,i}=0$ for $t-2$ numbers. This also means that $\min_i a_{k,i} = 0$ and hence $a_{k,i}=0$ for $t-1$ numbers. Hence, for any $t\geq3$, we need the numbers to be pairwise relatively prime.

Comment: Wouldn't that be equivalent with the gcd for any three numbers being $1$?

Comment: @user190865 I updated my argument.

Answer (score 0):

It is

$$gcd(2,4,8)=2$$ and

$$lcm(2,4,8)=8.$$

However,

$$lcm(2,4,8)gcd(2,4,8)=14\ne 64 =2\cdot 4\cdot 8.$$

So, for a sequence of length $3$ is false. You can construct a sequence having as many terms as you want adding $2'$s to the previous one.

Now, for sequences of two terms it is right. Can you prove it?

Comment: There are arbitrarily long sequences for which the equality holds.

Comment: I have said that it is possible to construct a sequence of arbitrary length ($\ge 3$) that doesn't satisfy the equality.

Comment: Yes. And I have added that it is possible to construct arbitrarily long sequences for which the equality holds. Together that implies that apart from the sufficient "length $\leqslant 2$", the length is not a criterion to determine whether it holds or not.

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right. I have misunderstood your comment.

Comment: I have to admit that I haven't formulated it in a way that makes misunderstanding it particularly difficult.